# Excel IF statement Not returning the appropriate Value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to grade students by giving them `A` or `B` depending on their score. If someone is having `absent` instead of a score, I return a value of the cell.

However, it does not return the value of the cell. The reference records are in a separate sheet called `raw`. I think it may be because I'm trying to return a string data.

I am using Excel 2007. Here's the formula:

```
=IF(raw!E6>=75,"AA",IF(raw!E6>=70,"AB",IF(raw!E6>=60,"B",IF(raw!E6>=50,"C",IF(raw!E6>=40,"D",IF(raw!E6<40,"RT",raw!E6))))))
```

Comment: Some general debugging advice: Take apart your `IF` formula piece by piece, and make sure that each piece is working.  Then, build up until either you arrive at the final formula, or until you hit the actual problem.

Comment: thanks...amma try that ryt away

Comment: `=IF(E6="absent",E6,IF(E6>=75,"AA",IF(E6>=70,"AB",IF(E6>=60,"B",IF(E6>=50,"C",IF(E6>=40,"D",IF(E6<40,"RT",E6)))))))` You forgot about the "Absent", not gonna post this as answer snice this probably doesn't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Nested IFs if you can avoid it. Instead, use a banded VLOOKUP: it's many times more efficient, and a heck of a lot simpler to troubleshoot. Something like this:

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER([@Score]),VLOOKUP([@Score],Table1,2,TRUE),"Absent")
```

Notes:

- The above uses Tables and the associated Table Notation. I always use
  Tables when I can, because they reduce spreadsheet administration and
  the Structured Table References have intrinsic meaning.
- The VLOOKUP must have TRUE as the forth argument, and the lookup
  table must be sorted in ascending order.
- The lowest score must be zero, so that anything below 40 gets a "Retake" grade.

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, the performance of Structured Refs is much improved in 2016 and later than they were in 2007 (which I note the OP has). I used to have issues with them back then, but now I find no noticeable performance difference, so it's pretty much all upside to my mind. In regards to not answering the question, you mean not giving an example that uses nested IF statements?

Comment: @pnuts I think the OP is having trouble returning "Absent" with the formula as written. It would need to be re-written along the lines of `=IF(ISNUMBER([@Score]),IF([@Score]>=75,"AA",IF([@Score]>=70,"AB",IF([@Score]>=60,"B",IF([@Score]>=50,"C",IF([@Score]>=40,"D",IF([@Score]<40,"RT")))))),"Absent")` if I'm understanding the requirement correctly. Re Structured Refs, this is worth a read: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2018/01/29/excel-2016-performance-improvements/

Comment: @pnuts Prebsus' answer incorrectly returns "AA" for Absent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not the students' scores are in whole percentage figures (i.e. 75, 63, etc), you could use the `INT`-function to force interpretation of the input field as an integer (not that it always round down a score, which I suppose seem to be ok with the nested if-structure you're using here. Your function would then be:

```
=IF(INT(raw!E6>=75),"AA",IF(INT(raw!E6)>=70,"AB",IF(INT(raw!E6)>=60,"B",IF(INT(raw!E6)>=50,"C",IF(INT(raw!E6)>=40,"D",IF(INT(raw!E6)<40,"RT",raw!E6))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to change you last IF condition (raw!E6<40,"RT) because excel will give RT to all the score which is below 40 so add a and condition like if raw!E6>0 , this should resolve your work

if(and(raw!E6<40mraw!E6>0),"RT,raw!E6)

Hope this helps