# Excel Multiple If Statements showing False

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have this IF statement:

```
=IF(AG3<=7,"1",IF(15<=AG3<=21,"2",IF(22<=AG3<=28,"3",IF(29<=AG3<=35,"4",IF(36<=AG3<=42,"5",IF(43<=AG3<=49,"6",IF(50<=AG3<=56,"7")))))))
```

but either it gives me a 1 or "FALSE"

All the values are within the ranges and should be showing various numbers

Comment: what about 8 through 14?

Comment: And what happens if the number is greater than 56?

Answer (score 3):

Excel does not use `50<=AG3<=56`. The way Excel will read this is it will resolve `AG3<=56` which will resolve to `TRUE` or `FALSE` which have the values of `1` and `0` respectively.  And since 50 is greater than both those it will always return `FALSE` and since you did not specify a final false argument Excel returns `FALSE`

It needs to be `AND(50<=AG3, AG3<=56)`

Also `"1"` returns a number as text and not a true number, remove the quotes.

So:

```
=IF(AG3<=7,1,IF(AND(15<=AG3,AG3<=21),2,IF(AND(22<=AG3,AG3<=28),3,IF(AND(29<=AG3,AG3<=35),4,IF(AND(36<=AG3,AG3<=42),5,IF(AND(43<=AG3,AG3<=49),6,IF(AND(50<=AG3,AG3<=56),7,"Value not in specs")))))))
```

But based on your criteria you could use:

```
=IF(OR(AND(AG3>=8,AG3<=14),AG3>56),"Not to Spec",MATCH(AG3,{-1E+99,15,22,29,36,43,40}))
```

Comment: Great solution. Personally, I like the way this concept is being explained.. reminds me of [better explained](https://betterexplained.com) concepts/way of understanding things. (:

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Nested IFs if you can avoid it. Instead, use a banded VLOOKUP: it's many times more efficient, and a heck of a lot simpler to troubleshoot. Something like the answer here:

[Excel IF statement Not returning the appropriate Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421402/excel-if-statement-not-returning-the-appropriate-value/51422683#51422683)

In your case, here's your lookup list:

[image]

Note that since you haven't specified what should happen between 8 and 14 or over 57 I have simply put =NA() in those bands.

And here's the result for a range of numbers:

[image]

...and here's the formula that was used in the second column of that second table (using table notation):
`=VLOOKUP([@Value],Table3,2,TRUE)`

Comment: I like Scott's solution, but this one is so obvious I am amazed I never saw the potential for it since I recall years ago having a sheet where I was grouping ranges similar to this and kept tweaking the amounts to try to find the proper ranges and resulting weights to assign. I started with a relatively simple if statement and ended up using two factors when I could have used your technique with a two-dimensional table and both ranges (and the resulting weights) could have been far more easily tweaked (in fact the weights could have been built with a formula), Now, to find that spreadsheet.